# Correct approach to ensure a rewritten URL always finds what you expect it to?

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having a play around with using `mod_rewrite` to provide a better looking URL to the user, and to search engines - as is fairly common practice on many dynamic websites.

So for instance, I began with:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/profile/view.php?id=136
```

Assuming user number 136 is called, for the sake of argument `Bob T. Smith the 3rd` (apologies Bob, if you exist).

As far as I understand it, I must have a variant of Bob's name in my 'nasty' URL, because you can only rewrite what exists - so i'd need to change my code so that this URL finds the profile we're looking for:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/profile/view.php?id=bob-t-smith-the-3rd
```

can now become

```
http://www.mydomain.com/profile/bob-t-smith-the-3rd
```

I'm using a custom function to convert underscores & spaces to dashes, strip any non alpha-numeric characters and then lower case everything to make the URL look really nice.

And so within my page, rather than looking up on the very unique primary key that is '136', I now have to look up on the users name - but the sanitized version, so i'm using something like this - because MySQL can't do regular expressions:

```
SELECT LOWER(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('Bob T. Smith the 3rd'," ","-"),"_","-"),".",""));
```

The name would obviously be replaced by whatever came in on the URL, cleaned up.

The problem i'm expecting is that without wanting to chain together MySQL REPLACE() functions to handle every conceivable illegal character (which would be confusing, hard to maintain, and probably inefficient), and without the ability to do regular expressions on the query side, how can I ensure the user profile is found and gets returned every single time?

If Bob signed up as '`Bob T. Smith! (The 3rd)`' - I would still clean that up in PHP to `bob-t-smith-the-3rd` because of the `preg_replace` that strips the exclamation point and the parentheses, but my query - unless I added more REPLACE() functions, wouldn't find that user.

Should I just ensure that users can only sign up using A-Z, 0-9, dash and underscore?

Should I in some way continue to pass the unique numerical ID but just omit it from the rewrite rule somehow?

Am I missing the point entirely?  Is there an accepted way of doing this that I just haven't thought of?

Thanks :-)

Comment: I think i've stumbled across another potential solution, and so far (in my brain) its working for me - when the user signs up as '`Bob T. Smith the 3rd`' - as well as storing that for logins, I could use my custom modRewriteEncode() function to store the stripped/sanitized version alongside it, for doing database lookups?  Anyone see a problem with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if I am missing something but why don't you just strip the username from the dashes you added in your rewrite rule when the php script is called?

```
$undashed_username = explode("-",$dashed_username);
$username = implode(" ",$undashed_username);
```

which you can then search for on your database.

Comment: Sorry, i'm not following you.  In the database its stored exactly as the user signed up, ie 'Bob T. Smith the 3rd' - so when the user logs in, they can use the name they signed up with.  In the friendly url, thats reduced to a lower case, no spaces, no punctuation version - which is then irreversible, and hard to match in the database.

Comment: I see. The only way to get a sure match is for both names to be the same. Your only possible solution for this would be to encode the punctuation, etc. as well so you can make a sure match. However I think you're walking into more problems by allowing punctuation in your usernames. Even if you applied the REPLACE rules two different users Bob. T Smith and Bob T. Smith (both have unique names) would result in the same rewritten username. I would suggest to only allow usernames you can encode with your desired scheme.

Comment: You have a valid point.  Your thoughts on the comment I added the question - ie, storing the sanitized version at user sign-up time (which could be checked for duplicates in PHP) - do you think that would work?

Comment: That would work in my opinion. That simplifies your search for the correct profile to a match with the database. It is a trade-off though. You make the matching simpler but you use up more space in your database to store "redundant" data.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make this request?

```
http://www.mydomain.com/profile/bob-t-smith-the-3rd?id=136
```

So you have a nice URL and you do not need to deal with actually searching for the username.

If you fear to have `?` inside of your URL you can do this as well:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/profile/136/bob-t-smith-the-3rd
```

And then parsing the numeric information from the request string.

This will also reduce the work of the database as well.

Comment: My first thought on this is that you don't really see that on other sites, although its hard to tell if they are rewriting URLs, or they just set up physcial pages.  Assuming they are doing rewrites, they're not including numerical IDs in their friendly URLS - so I was wondering if they were somehow passing the ID to do their query, but omitting it from the rewritten version..?

Comment: Sure sites do include numerical IDs in their friendly URLs. Just see the link to my profile here on SE - for example:

Comment: If you do not like `profile/136/bob-t-smith-the-3rd` because it looks like you are having a folder, consider this one (which is almost the same) `profile/136-bob-t-smith-the-3rd` -- you can easily extract id from such URL

Comment: Have a look at my comment on the question - perhaps I should just store 'bob-t-smith-the-3rd' in the database alongside the user name when he signs up, and ensure its unique?

Comment: You can do so as well, but searching for strings in the database is more work than searching for a unique (numerical) id. If you do not want any numbers, then you need something else unique to search for. So it depends how much luxury you can afford.